# Spark writing to postgresql

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to transfer 2 million records from MongoDB to Postgres with Apache Spark (using the official drivers for both databases). After a few minutes the program stops and I find these errors in the postgres log:
`2017-12-03T22:18:16+00:00 app[postgres.15348]: [AQUA] [7-1]  sql_error_code = 26000 ERROR:  prepared statement "S_4" does not exist`
. Anyone who has experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://www.torodb.com, which provides a full MongoDB to PostgreSQL migration solution, fully automated. The product is Open Source.